# How to differentiate Sie (they) or Sie (you)?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, noun, grammatical-case, pronoun

> Sie haben meine Brieftasche.

This sentence has 2 different meanings -

> They have my wallet.

or

> You have my wallet.

How can I know which is intended?

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4789/how-to-differentiate-between-sie-they-and-sie-she and http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7159/isnt-sie-always-supposed-to-be-capitalized

Comment: Context. Neither in English nor German you can know whether "You have my wallet" addresses one person or multiple

Comment: In English you will say `They have my wallet` for plural.

Comment: In Englisg, 'you' can be plural, equivalent to German 'ihr'. As in German, it is the context that matters.

Comment: You can say "you all". How do you make a clear distincion of "you" vs "they" in german?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In that sentence it is not possible to differentiate the meaning of *Sie*. You need either a context or the possibility to see if *Sie* is capitalized because of the punctuation, or because of its meaning as "formal you". For instance:

> — Haben Sie meine Brieftasche gesehen? Ich habe sie verloren.
>   — *Möglichkeit A*: Ja, sie haben Ihre Brieftasche. (*they*-meaning)
>   — *Möglichkeit B*: Ja, Sie haben Ihre Brieftasche in den Händen. (*"Formal you"*-meaning; ok, it happens sometimes to me).

More logical:

> — Haben Sie meinen Bleistift gesehen?
>   — *Möglichkeit A*: Ja, sie haben Ihren Bleistift. (*they*-meaning)
>   — *Möglichkeit B*: Ja, Sie haben Ihren Bleistift hinterm Ohr. (*"Formal you"*-meaning).

Comment: Note that capitalization is not reliable. Unbelievably many Germans, even print journalists, get it wrong.

Comment: plus with the introduction of the new german orthography several years ago, even the "formal you"-meaning is by default non-capitalized "but may optionally be capitalized"... so you will need the context in order to determine the meaning

Comment: @Ingo: That's wrong; you are confusing _Sie_ and _du_. For the situation regarding _du_, see http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7379 (in German) or http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/211 (in English). This question here is about _Sie_ and _sie_, where the capitalization is, in theory, always unambiguously defined and you never have a choice.

Comment: To make matters more confusing, the first example should formally be "Haben Sie meine Brieftasche gesehen? Ich habe sie verloren." Using "die" as reference for "Brieftasche" here is colloquial.

Answer (score 7):

That depends on the context. If you talk to someone (single person or sometimes multiple persons, but the informal "ihr" is more common here) it means "you", if you are talking about some people (multiple persons) it means "they".

Comment: Oh, I forgot the capitalization c.p. and chirlu mentioned. I didn't think about written words.

Answer (score 6):

If you say **"They have my wallet."** in English, then you can also say "Die haben meine Brieftasche." And then it is obvious again. Otherwise you need to go by context.
If no context is given, you have to ask whom do you mean? Answer: "The ... took my wallet."