# What is the difference between Du and Sie

Tags: grammar, pronoun

What is the difference between Du and Sie? For example, you are drinking/ you drink translates to

```
Du trinkst
Sie trinken
```

other than the difference in conjugation, I do not understand why I would use one or the other.

Comment: [http://www.dw.de/the-du-sie-dilemma-in-german/a-16494631](http://www.dw.de/the-du-sie-dilemma-in-german/a-16494631)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz sorry about the confusion

Comment: Was any effort made to look this up on your own from any grammar source or quick online check?

Comment: These question may give you a clue and further informations. http://german.stackexchange.com/q/77/1224 - http://german.stackexchange.com/q/9469/1224 – Did you made any attempt to answer this question by searching the Internet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Du` is used with people that you know very well:

> Du trinkst eine Tasse Kaffee.
>
> Du gehst jeden Tag in die Schule.

`Sie`is the formal form `you` and it is used with people you don't  know very well. It is also used in formal writing and such:

> Kommen Sie bitte hierher!

Always remember that its always written in a capital letter and not to be confused with `sie` which is `they`.

Comment: So that is similar to Spanish where du it like tu, you (informal), and sie is like usted, you (formal).

Comment: Yes, but if you wanna address a bunch of people you know it's `Ihr` which is `vosotros/as` in Spanish, but if a bunch of people you're not familiar with you use `Sie`

Comment: @user1876508, yes, it is similar, but the social norms governing its use are probably different. Check out the answers to http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/77/how-can-a-native-english-speaker-know-when-it-is-appropriate-to-use-the-polite for some guidance.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 if i'm not mistaken **ihr** also means you in plural form.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 Also, please provide English translation of your examples as well for newbies like me.

Answer (score 4):

### Du versus Sie (and ihr)

`Du` (informal singular): you use this form with family, close friends, children, pets, deities, and if you're younger, your peers

> Gehst du heute in die Schule?

`Sie` (formal singular and plural): Pretty much in every other situations, you use *Sie*.*Sie* is especially used with adult strangers, and generally among white-collar colleagues (office, bank, etc vs a blue-collar job) or other professional environment. Technically, *Sie* is also the plural and thus if you would *siezen* the individuals in the group you'd *siezen* them as a whole.

> Haben Sie den Bericht geschrieben?

`ihr` (plural): this form is technically the plural of *du* (you all), but is sometimes used collectively towards people you'd use *Sie* with individually.

> Ihr müsst das Projekt bald fertig machen.

---

As you may have seen, *Sie* and all its forms are always capitalized

> Sie haben die Ampel überfahren
>
> Ich habe das für Sie mitgebracht
>
> Das passt Ihnen gut
>
> Ist das Ihr Hemd?

*Du* and *ihr* and their respective forms can be capitalized, but it's not required like it is with *Sie*

Another more prominent difference in conjugation

> Du bist
>
> Du warst
>
> Du gehst
>
> Du machtest
>
> ---
>
> Sie sind
>
> Sie waren
>
> Sie gehen
>
> Sie machten

---

You may have also noticed that *Sie* (you) and *sie* (them) match up in spelling, pronunciation and conjugation. The only way to tell the difference is context; it's usually reasonably clear. In 2 and half years of learning German, I can't remember one time when I the two words being the same tripped me up.

---

It's hard to draw a line between the two words, because German is a living language so who you can *duzen* and who you should *siezen* is constantly changing and different people have different views and ideas about the two. [Doing a search on this StackExchange](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=du%20sie) shows how hard it can be and how there can be many different cases.

---

*Du* vs *Sie* should not be compared with *tu* versus vous or *tú* versus *Ud.* in French and Spanish respectively, because these languages all define the distinction differently.

---

Other Resources

[The 'du/Sie' dilemma in German](http://www.dw.de/the-du-sie-dilemma-in-german/a-16494631)

[When to use du and Sie](http://bibliobrary.net/2010/01/04/when-to-use-du-and-sie/)

[Du and Sie](http://www.languagerealm.com/german/du_sie.php)

[The du und du waltz](http://www.economist.com/node/14973174)

Comment: some things i'm hanging up on: *"Bericht"* is male, thus: *"Haben sie ---die--- den Bericht geschrieben?"*, also you state *"Sie and all it's Forms are capitalized."* It's not really clear that you mean the singular *Sie* only...